# Magento - Unable to access remote site but able to access a simple index.html file

Tags: php, apache, magento, localhost

I'm building a store (magento 1.6.0.0-rc2) and have a home server to host the site.
It is behind a modem/router with redirection of port 80 and 3000 active to server box.

1. I can access the front-end and back-end from localhost (Slackware Linux).

2. Configured a no-ip account with a host name with 'Port 80 Redirect' enabled.
example: `store1.no-ip.biz`

3. If I try to access the site from another network, I get

> Unable to connect
>
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:3000.

A strange thing is that the message returns 'localhost'...

4. but I created a simple *index.html* file and saved it in the root directory, side by side with index.php, and **I can access it** without any problem.
Permission of these two files are 640, owner myself and group apache (the one httpd runs with).

5. I have no firewall active, hosts.deny is clear.

6. In **httpd.conf** I have:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php index.php3 index.php4 index.php5
</IfModule>

LoadModule authz_host_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule log_config_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_log_config.so 
LoadModule setenvif_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_setenvif.so 
LoadModule mime_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_mime.so 
LoadModule dir_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_dir.so 
LoadModule alias_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so 
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so

Include /etc/httpd/mod_php.conf
Include /etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

7. In the virtual host I have:

```
 <VirtualHost *:3000>
    ServerName store1.no-ip.biz
    UseCanonicalName Off
    DocumentRoot "/home/larrobag/lio/apache/magento/"
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/lio_error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/lio-access_log" common
    LimitRequestBody 300000

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing?  I'd appreciate any clues on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[LazyOne](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/8354/lazyone) says (pasted from a comment which the original poster indicated solved the problem):

> As far as I remember the server name (domain name) used when Magento was installed is used when building/requesting URLs. You do not see it when accessing `.html` file as it is static file, but you see it when accessing Magento-powered PHP file. Check the Magento settings for localhost and replace all occurrences (except DB and similar) with `store1.no-ip.biz`. At least this is what I was doing when moving Magento from local to live server when I was using it.